# how to get CMake to add MagickWand library linking automatically everywhere

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, imagemagick, magickwand

I want to use CMake in my software that uses MagickWand.

CMake works on my machine and generates a useful Makefile.
On another machine, I have to manually add

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lMagickWand-6.Q16 -lMagickCore-6.Q16")
```

otherwise the linker can't find MagickWandGenesis() and other functions.

I found that -l flags via `pkg-config --cflags --libs MagickWand`.

Shouldn't CMake already generate linker flags for me with `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES`?

Did I miss something obvious, or why is this not working everywhere?

---

I have this code in CMakeLists.txt:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(ImageMagick
  REQUIRED
  COMPONENTS MagickWand
)
```

[...]

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16")
```

[...]

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${ImageMagick_MagickWand_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

[...]

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(application_name
  [...]
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  ${CURL_LIBRARIES}
  ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES}
  ${ImageMagick_MagickWand_LIBRARY}
)
```

That last `${ImageMagick_MagickWand_LIBRARY}` shouldn't even be necessary.

Using Magick 6.8.9.9, CMake 3.0.2 on both machines (Debian Jessie).

Comment: Either the environments on the two machines *do* differ or it's a bug/insufficiency of the FindImageMagick module. *Edit*: Did you try to debug FindImageMagick by printing the contents of the variables set my the find module?

Comment: Yeah, I printed all the variables (see my own answer) and got identical output on both machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: the package `ImageMagick` is buggy.

Looking in [CMake's sources](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmFindPackageCommand.cxx#L638), the `REQUIRED` mechanism is handled exclusively through the variable package-`_FOUND`, independently of the required components.

Looking in the package `ImageMagick` [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindImageMagick.cmake#L273), `ImageMagick_FOUND` is set as follows:

```
set(ImageMagick_FOUND ${IMAGEMAGICK_FOUND})
```

But `IMAGEMAGICK_FOUND` is not set anywhere in the package, so the call will always unset `ImageMagick_FOUND`, and it will always be evaluated to **true** (not actively set to **false**), wether or not the components are effectively found.

You can either debug the package (and propose a pull request) or check the component variable:

```
if(NOT ImageMagick_MagickWand_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "MagickWand not found")
endif()
```

I guess the test will fail on your second machine.

---

By the way, you should only use `ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `ImageMagick_LIBRARIES` to link to the library (the `ImageMagick_MagickWand*` variables are here redundant). If you choose to debug the package, you may also declare imported targets.

Comment: `But IMAGEMAGICK_FOUND is not set anywhere in the package` - Variable *IMAGEMAGICK_FOUND* is set by previous call to `FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS`. Actually, this call sets both *ImageMagick_FOUND* and *IMAGEMAGICK_FOUND* variables, so the call to `set()` you refer to is redudant (but it can be meaningfull for backward compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, despite the output of

```
MESSAGE(${ImageMagick_FOUND})
MESSAGE(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})
MESSAGE(${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES})
MESSAGE(${ImageMagick_MagickWand_FOUND})
MESSAGE(${ImageMagick_MagickWand_INCLUDE_DIRS})
MESSAGE(${ImageMagick_MagickWand_LIBRARY})
```

being identical, the installed packages differed. I installed the magick-dev packages via virtual packages in aptitude, which for some reason used the `graphicsmagick` suite for some packages (a imagemagick fork) instead of the original imagemagick suite.

For reference, the used aptitude search one-liner was `aptitude search 'magick ?installed' | sort` which listed three graphicsmagick packages on the second machine where imagemagick packages were on the first machine.